# How to detect Iphone/Ipad devices with bluetooth ON?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, bluetooth

I am using BluetoothManager.framework

I have the sample example for detecting bluetooth device of iphone/ipad. But this sample app is not detecting my devices.

Below is the link for sample code and url:

http://www.pocketmagic.net/2012/07/bluetooth-and-ios-use-bluetooth-in-your-iphone-apps/#.URnZy-hhNDQ

```
BluetoothManager *btManager;

- (IBAction)scanButtonAction
{
  if ([btManager enabled])
  {
        // start scan
        [btManager  setDeviceScanningEnabled:YES];
   }
   else
   {
    showMessage(@"Error", @"Turn Bluetooth on first!");
   }

}

- (IBAction)bluetoothON
{
    NSLog(@"bluetoothON called.");
    [btManager setPowered:YES];
    [btManager setEnabled:YES]; 
}

- (IBAction)bluetoothOFF
{
    NSLog(@"bluetoothOFF called.");
    [btManager setEnabled:NO]; 
    [btManager setPowered:NO];
}
```

Any suggestions or samples to detect bluetooth devices will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of bluetooth use your bluetooth device? Bluetooth 4.0? If yes it is probably better when you use the CoreBluetooth framework especially it is not private. 
Using bluetooth you have to create a CBCentralManager instance. Than you have to implement the CBCentralManagerDelegate protocol an the CBPeripheralDelegate protocol. You can test if your hardware support Bluetooth 4.0 by asking the CBCentralManager state. For example: CBCentralMangerStateUnsupported mean that your hardware doesn't support BT 4.0.

Comment: I have two iphones with same Bluetooth not connecting with each other.
Eventhough devices are of same version and bluetooth are of same kind.

Comment: in this case you can use Bluetooth 4.0. With iOS 6 a iPhone can also i Bluetooth peripheral like e.g. a heartratmonitor. For details and how you can implement Bluetooth 4 download the [BTLE Central Peripheral Transfer samplecode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/BTLE_Transfer/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40012927) from Apple.